# How can request handlers communicate in Django?

Tags: django, process, global-variables

If you make a long-running http request to a Django application, can you send a second request to communicate with it?  Can you share data between requests?

Pylons has a concept of application globals.  Top level variables in node.js are all application globals.  How can I do this in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally considered a bad idea, so I'm going to show you how it would usually be done.  Most of the time, long-running tasks should be forked to the background, and updates from that task get placed in a global store (such as your database, [memcached](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#memcached), or similar).  This keeps your front-end server from getting bogged down with too many requests.

Using memcached (or any of the [django cache backends](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/)), your code might look something like:

```
def long_running_task(number):
    cache.set("long_running_task_progress", 0, 60*60) # Store for 1 hour.
    for x in range(0, number):
        huge_calculation(number)
        cache.set("long_running_task_progress", (x / number), 60*60)
    cache.delete("long_running_task_progress")

def check_long_task(request):
    percent = cache.get("long_running_task_progress")
    if percent is None:
        return HttpResponse("There is no task running!")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("The task is %.2f percent complete." % (percent * 100))
```

Simply load the latter on an AJAX timer, and plop it into the page as needed.

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach. Look into [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) which manages this sort of thing for you.